# Image processing, pixel by pixel, takes a long time

Tags: android, image, algorithm

I'm writing an Android application which processes an image pixel by pixel. To read and set the pixels I use two nested loops.

This process is very time-consuming. Even if I delete the instructions in the loops, it takes about a minute to run on an 8 megapixel image.

Why is it taking so long? Are there any other ways to get and set pixels?

```
    long mn = img_w*img_h;
    long o = 0;
    for(int i =0;i<img_w;i++) {
        for(int j=0;j<img_h;j++) {

                System.out.println(mn-o);

        o++;

        }
    }
```

This code simulate processing image, and this code take very long time

logcat (section):

```
    02-12 19:01:40.815: I/System.out(332): 4999.0
02-12 19:01:40.815: I/System.out(332): 4998.0
02-12 19:01:40.815: I/System.out(332): 4997.0
02-12 19:01:40.825: I/System.out(332): 4996.0
02-12 19:01:40.825: I/System.out(332): 4995.0
02-12 19:01:40.825: I/System.out(332): 4994.0
02-12 19:01:40.825: I/System.out(332): 4993.0
02-12 19:01:40.825: I/System.out(332): 4992.0
02-12 19:01:40.825: I/System.out(332): 4991.0
02-12 19:01:40.825: I/System.out(332): 4990.0
02-12 19:01:40.835: I/System.out(332): 4989.0
02-12 19:01:40.835: I/System.out(332): 4988.0
02-12 19:01:40.835: I/System.out(332): 4987.0
02-12 19:01:40.835: I/System.out(332): 4986.0
02-12 19:01:40.845: I/System.out(332): 4985.0
02-12 19:01:40.845: I/System.out(332): 4984.0
02-12 19:01:40.845: I/System.out(332): 4983.0
02-12 19:01:40.845: I/System.out(332): 4982.0
02-12 19:01:40.845: I/System.out(332): 4981.0
02-12 19:01:40.845: I/System.out(332): 4980.0
02-12 19:01:40.845: I/System.out(332): 4979.0
02-12 19:01:40.845: I/System.out(332): 4978.0
02-12 19:01:40.855: I/System.out(332): 4977.0
02-12 19:01:40.855: I/System.out(332): 4976.0
02-12 19:01:40.855: I/System.out(332): 4975.0
02-12 19:01:40.855: I/System.out(332): 4974.0
02-12 19:01:40.855: I/System.out(332): 4973.0
02-12 19:01:40.865: I/System.out(332): 4972.0
```

Comment: You will have to either develop or implement an algorithm with complexity less then O(N^2). If you can explain what it is exactly that you're doing, others might be able to suggest something.

Comment: If you are deleting the instructions and it still takes a minute, the problem is else where. Correct me if im wrong, but the compiler would remove the for loops completely (as they do nothing), so would not cause the delay still.

Comment: @ Doomsknight but this loops displays information in commandline :)

Comment: If you're running through an 8 megapixel image and displaying information in the command line, this is why it's slow. Java will wait for the information to be written to the log before continuing, and when doing this 8 million times, of course it takes a while. Consider doing it once every `i` instead of once every `j` iteration.

Comment: Basically: your loop takes about 50 milliseconds (give or take) to process 30 iterations. If you have 5000 iterations it (like your code seems to imply) you have about 8333 milliseconds of time covered there. So, like I've been saying: it looks like your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: as h2ooooo stated, you can use something like `while(i++<height){write(fd,data,width);data+=width;}` you'll probably need some extra code, this is just a template based on char data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can solve your problem in Java in this manner. There are overheads involved in executing Java statements (and method calls in particular) and doing this 8 million times - even if the instructions do almost nothing, like setting a value - will always be slow.

The standard answer would be to implement this function in C++ which is compiled instead of interpreted by the Java Virtual Machine, and hence should be faster. It still probably won't be fast enough for a real time application; you are still doing something 8 million times, just less each time.

Doing peek and poke operations in Java across an entire 8 Mb pixel buffer isn't ever going to be fast. However, the designers of Java were aware of this issue, which is why they provide the extended 2D graphics API to often eliminate the need for for loops that execute a million times. I would recommend having a closer look at the 2D API library, which is designed to set and read bits in a bitmap. Depending on what you are really trying to do, there may be much faster ways. You can set up a bitmap with transparent background, and write your changes to this bitmap, and write the bitmap on top of the previous image. When you write bitmaps on top of bitmaps, you can set up a Paint class which will manipulate the impressed image (eg by applying variable transparency to it). The Android 2d Graphics API also supports "Porter-Duff" compositing which provides calls which allow images to be combined in novel ways. All of these are essentially performed in hardware, and hence are extremely fast.

Without knowing what you are trying to do (exactly), I can't tell you how to do it more efficiently, but in a lot of cases there is a far more efficient implementation than the brute force approach you are using. If there isn't, and you want this real time, I suspect you are stuffed.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have arranged your loops is very cache unfriendly. Make the inner loop pass over the width and the outer loop pass over the height.

Comment: that sounds interesting. Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: OK I replaced loops and I deleted "System.out" but the problem remained. In logcat isn't any errors.Just the application is executed but very long on the device. I noticed that the in emulator for some smaller pictures the whole process is done much faster

Comment: I wouldn't be looking for errors in the logcat. What I would be looking for is for the timestamp between iterations.